# Is there a way to serialize and deserialize a Faraday::Response without loosing any information?

Tags: ruby, faraday

I am trying to serialize a `Faraday::Response` instance without losing any information.
I found the `marshal_dump` and `marshal_load` methods but they don't seem to keep the `response.env.request` details.

```rb
response = Faraday.get('https://google.com')
response.env.request_headers
#=> {"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v2.7.4"}

response2 = Faraday::Response.new
response2.marshal_load(response.marshal_dump)
response2.env.request_headers
#=> nil

response3 = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(response))
response3.env.request_headers
#=> nil
```

How can I serialize everything so that upon deserializing, both objects contain the exact same data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> without losing any information

In general this is not really possible. For instance the request has `@on_complete_callbacks` which are procs, and those can't be marshalled.
On top - an object can reference other objects, and in some cases (e.g. anonymous classes) those also can't be marshalled.

Faraday's `marshal_dump` is just this

```
def marshal_dump
  finished? ? to_hash : nil
end
```

(source: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/lostisland/faraday/Faraday/Response#marshal_dump-instance_method)

and `to_hash` is:

```
def to_hash
  {
    status: env.status, body: env.body,
    response_headers: env.response_headers,
    url: env.url
  }
end
```

(source: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/lostisland/faraday/Faraday/Response#to_hash-instance_method)

so, as you can see - the developers of Faraday made a decision that everything else it not that important.

So, the shortcut "just serialize in a way that after deserialization it's exactly the same" is not possible, so you either need to:

- implement your own object (e.g. wrapper) in which you can implement your own serialization, but you'll have to decide which data is important
- or, reformulate your original problem you're trying to solve and try to look for other possible solutions (you're not sharing why you need that, so it's hard to help you with that).